# Merge/combine the array data based on the date without duplicating in angular

Tags: javascript, typescript

How to merge array data based on the date without duplicating?

Here's the code:

```
[
 {
  date: [ '2019-12-02 08:00:00', '2019-12-03 08:00:00' ],
  upload:["47.93", "47.46", "47.40", "47.29" ],
  download: ["43.90", "41.12", "46.80", "47.86", "47.69", "47.74" ],
  ping: ["3.607", "4.209", "4.052", "3.559", "3.8"]
 }
],[
 {
  date: [ '2019-12-02 08:00:00', '2019-12-04 08:00:00' ],
  upload: [ "47.93", "47.46", "41.40", "52.30" ],
  download: [ "47.90", "47.12", "46.80", "47.86", "47.69", "47.74" ],
  ping: ["3.607", "4.209", "4.052", "1.559", "3.2" ]
 }
]
```

Here's the expected output:

```
[
{
date : [ '2019-12-04 08:00:00', '2019-12-02 08:00:00', '2019-12-03 08:00:00']
data: [
 0: {
  upload:["47.93", "47.46", "47.40", "47.29" ],
  download: ["43.90", "41.12", "46.80", "47.86", "47.69", "47.74" ],
  ping: ["3.607", "4.209", "4.052", "3.559", "3.8"]
 },
 1: {
  upload: [ "47.93", "47.46", "41.40", "52.30" ],
  download: [ "47.90", "47.12", "46.80", "47.86", "47.69", "47.74" ],
  ping: ["3.607", "4.209", "4.052", "1.559", "3.2" ]
}
 ]
```

Then when it merge the data it will based on the date and it shouldn't duplicate the dates when it merging.

Answer (score -2):

the closes thing I could think of is that you can Iterate all data then do an inner loop for checking result dates to the data.date and check if it exists otherwise continue to check. at the end of the inner loop do a check if exists to update existing data otherwise append a new one;

```js
// initial data array
const a = [{
    date: ['2019-12-02 08:00:00', '2019-12-03 08:00:00'],
    upload: ["47.93", "47.46", "47.40", "47.29"],
    download: ["43.90", "41.12", "46.80", "47.86", "47.69", "47.74"],
    ping: ["3.607", "4.209", "4.052", "3.559", "3.8"]
}, {
    date: ['2019-12-02 08:00:00', '2019-12-04 08:00:00'],
    upload: ["47.93", "47.46", "41.40", "52.30"],
    download: ["47.90", "47.12", "46.80", "47.86", "47.69", "47.74"],
    ping: ["3.607", "4.209", "4.052", "1.559", "3.2"]
}];

// iterate initial data
const result = a.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let exists = false;
    let curr_idx = null;
    // iterate dates
    for (const date of item.date) {
        // check if current result date contains current date data
        for (const [idx, obj] of acc.entries()) {
            exists = obj.date.indexOf(date) >= 0;
            if (exists) {
                curr_idx = idx;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (exists) {
            break;
        }
    }
    if (exists) {
        acc[curr_idx].date = Array.from(new Set(acc[curr_idx].date.concat(item.date)))
        acc[curr_idx].data.push({
            upload: item.upload,
            download: item.download,
            ping: item.ping
        })
    } else {
        acc.push({
            date: item.date,
            data: [{
                upload: item.upload,
                download: item.download,
                ping: item.ping
            }]
        })
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
```